# explanation of the function assert

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to use function assert, but it's doesn't working. Writing "Assertion error". Can you explain why.

```
def parse(query: str) -> dict:
return {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
assert parse('https://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple') == {'name': 'ferret', 'color': 'purple'}
assert parse('https://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple&') == {'name': 'ferret', 'color': 'purple'}
assert parse('http://example.com/') == {}
assert parse('http://example.com/?') == {}
assert parse('http://example.com/?name=John') == {'name': 'John'}

def parse_cookie(query: str) -> dict:
return {}


if __name__ == '__main__':
assert parse_cookie('name=John;') == {'name': 'John'}
assert parse_cookie('') == {}
assert parse_cookie('name=John;age=28;') == {'name': 'John', 'age': '28'}
assert parse_cookie('name=John=User;age=28;') == {'name': 'John=User', 'age': '28'}
```

Comment: Because neither of your functions has any real implementation? Also note assert _isn't_ a function, it's a statement: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement

Answer (score 0):

`assert` does exactly that - it **asserts** that the expression following it is true. In your case it means that this expression is false (it returned `None` or a non-truthy value). It is typically used in testing code to, well, assert that test condition is true and fail a test otherwise.
Normally you do not use `assert` outside of tests though, the only exception would be a case where you test for a condition that absolutely must not happen and the program should be stopped if the control flow ever comes to evaluate that particular assert as true.

Comment: i understand, but I want to know, why writing Assertion error in this "code"

Comment: because a comparison right after the assert statement returned `False`. You are comparing an empty dictionary to a non-empty dictionary, so you are obviously getting a `False` which triggers your `asserts` to stop code execution.

Answer (score -1):

Assert is used when debugging code, meaning if the condition is true then nothing will happen and if the condition is false then AssertionError is raised.
But keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a toturial website and you need to ask the question more specificly so we can help you with your code, Hope i helped :)